# What's the best way to recreate a gitlab server to fix corrupted data?

Tags: git, gitlab

We have an internal private gitlab server hosted in our company.

This server contains some corrupted data, which cause some weird phenomena (for example, newly created users see 404 error when viewing the projects that they have been added into).

The corrupted data are caused by [running 2 docker containers that mount to the same volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54760637/some-gitlab-projects-return-404-error-after-accidentally-mounting-two-sets-of-do).

I don't think I can fix the corrupted data by editing files or configurations on the server. Because it's too risky. I may end up making the service unavailable. This would affect all the developers in my company.

So here are the things I want to do:

1. Create a new empty gitlab server.
2. Download all the branches of all projects on the original gitlab server using `git clone ...` and `git checkout ...`.
3. Create all the users and groups that are exactly the same as the original gitlab server on the new gitlab server manually.
4. Push all the projects to the new gitlab server.

But the above steps take a lot of time to prepare. Are there any better approaches to recreate a new gitlab server to fix the problems?

I've tried the [back up and restore](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html) feature of gitlab. The weird phenomenon still exist after the restore.

I run gitlab community edition 10.5.6 inside docker containers.

Comment: Why do you expect manually migrating data to work any better than backing up and restoring? If you're dealing with actual bugs your best bet is probably to upgrade. GitLab [10.5.6 is over a year old](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1056-2018-03-16). In any case, this is probably too broad and / or opinion-based to be on-topic here.

Comment: Because the bugs are created by me, not by the code of gitlab. The bugs didn't exist before [I ran 2 docker containers that mount the same volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54760637/some-gitlab-projects-return-404-error-after-accidentally-mounting-two-sets-of-do). Backing up and restoring doesn't solve the bugs.

Comment: Looking at your other question, it looks like you think your GitLab database is damaged? (Personally, I wouldn't call that a "bug".) It would probably be helpful to include that information in this question. Otherwise, the correct answer is to upgrade GitLab and, if necessary, use its back up and restore function.

Comment: Yes, I think my gitlab database is damaged. I think I shall not use the word *bug* to describe the weird phenomenon I encountered in the gitlab service.

Comment: Thanks for updating your question. I guess you don't have any clean backups, from before the corruption occurred? Do you just have repositories, or are you also using wikis and issue trackers?

Comment: I do not have any clean backups. We linked issues on jira to gitlab. I think the issue trackers must be rebuilt manually.

Comment: And when you tried to backup and restore your existing server before, did you restore to the same GitLab instance or a new one? If a new one, was it also configured with two containers mounting the same volume?

Comment: I restored the backup to a new gitlab. The new gitlab's volume did not overlap with another docker container's volume.

Comment: I've used [python-gitlab](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to copy all the projects, users, and groups to a new gitlab server. Everything works smoothly now. No weird phenomena anymore.